# Include multiple Mage.php into an external script

Tags: magento-1.9, php, migration

Is it possible to include multiple Magento (`Mage.php`) instances into the same external script and run them simultaneously?

My idea is to develop an external migration tool between two Magento systems, where entities from one instance will be directly transferred into the other one.

Normally I can load `Mage` via:

```
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();
```

But can I do something like:

```
require_once('../old/app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento (1st instance)
require_once('../new/app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento (2st instance)
umask(0);
Mage::app();  //This would probably not work anymore, if I include more than one Mage.php?..
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. PHP can not have two classes with the same name in one script execution.

There are solutions out there for more generic PHP cases that will suggest to rewrite the class source or try to move the classes into namespaces, but with the `Mage` class in Magento this is impossible.

Throughout the whole core Magento code there are references to `Mage` in the form of static calls, like `Mage::app()`. PHP would not know which `Mage` to use (if it where possible to run both).

I suggest you use some form of in between data storage. You could first get all entity data from one system and put it into a database or object storage (or dump JSON to files). Then run the other system and pull the data from the data storage and save it to that Magento.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I'll try to do it like that and post my results here, if I'm successful.